# Heap Memory in C Programming

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

What exactly is heap memory?

Whenever a call to malloc is made, memory is assigned from something called as heap. Where exactly is heap. I know that a program in main memory is divided into instruction segment where program statements are presents, Data segment where global data resides and stack segment where local variables and corresponding function parameters are stored. Now, what about heap?

Answer (score 15):

The heap is part of your process's address space. The heap can be grown or shrunk; you manipulate it by calling `brk(2)` or `sbrk(2)`.  This is in fact what `malloc(3)` does.

Allocating from the heap is more convenient than allocating memory on the stack because it persists after the calling routine returns; thus, you can call a routine, say `funcA()`, to allocate a bunch of memory and fill it with something; that memory will still be valid after `funcA()` returns.  If `funcA()` allocates a local array (on the stack) then when `funcA()` returns, the on-stack array is gone.

A drawback of using the heap is that if you forget to release heap-allocated memory, you may exhaust it.  The failure to release heap-allocated memory (e.g., failing to `free()` memory gotten from `malloc()`) is sometimes called a **memory leak**.

Another nice feature of the heap, vs. just allocating a local array/struct/whatever on the stack, is that you get a return value saying whether your allocation succeeded; if you try to allocate a local array on the stack and you run out, you don't get an error code; typically your thread will simply be aborted.

Comment: "Allocating from the heap is more convenient than allocating memory on the stack because it persists after the calling routine return" -- the logic here is incomplete and invalid; it should read more like "Allocating from the heap is more convenient than allocating on the stack because [we use memory that persists after the calling routine return and] it persists after the calling routine return." Now you should see one thing that's wrong with that; in not all cases do we need memory with such persistence, and calling `free` when not needed is *not more convenient*, contrary to the assertion.

Comment: Furthermore, even when you do use memory which requires a lifetime beyond that of the immediate function, you have two other options: **1/ preferably (and this should be your goal most of the time) you should accept an argument pointing to an object, and that object can have *any* storage duration; the caller decides whether `malloc` is necessary (this is how `strcat`, `sprintf`, etc operate)** and 2/ there are two other storage durations which you've not mentioned (static and thread-specific), and it's not specified whether they're attached to a *heap* or a *stack* (or *registers*, fwiw)...

Comment: There's even often a third option, which is up-stream, where-by you remove the dependency upon variadic arrays and focus on processing fixed data byte-by-byte (without keeping a copy) as you receive it from the source. In fact, you could almost refer to the regular filesystem as though it's another form of *storage duration*, except that the C standard doesn't define files very strictly.

Answer (score 10):

The heap is the diametrical opposite of the stack. The heap is a large pool of memory that can be used dynamically – it is also known as the “free store”. This is memory that is not automatically managed – you have to explicitly allocate (using functions such as malloc), and deallocate (e.g. free) the memory. Failure to free the memory when you are finished with it will result in what is known as a memory leak – memory that is still “being used”, and not available to other processes. Unlike the stack, there are generally no restrictions on the size of the heap (or the variables it creates), other than the physical size of memory in the machine. Variables created on the heap are accessible anywhere in the program.

Oh, and heap memory requires you to use pointers.

A summary of the heap:

- the heap is managed by the programmer, the ability to modify it is
  somewhat boundless
- in C, variables are allocated and freed using functions like malloc() and free()
- the heap is large, and is usually limited by the physical memory available
- the heap requires pointers to access it

credit to craftofcoding

Comment: A comprehensive answer to the question; I do have a few suggestions, though. For a start, you probably meant to write "Objects created on the heap are accessible anywhere in the program." rather than "Variables created on the heap are accessible anywhere in the program." Secondly, though the programmer perhaps indirectly manipulates the heap by calling `malloc`, the ability for the programmer to modify such an underlying structure is not *somewhat boundless*; if you step too far, you venture into *undefined behaviour*, which is where you've broken the rules of C.

Comment: Breaking the rules in C may appear as though you've stepped across a boundary. In fact, that is the case for buffer overflows, for example. Sometimes you get an overflow that works... other times, you don't. Breaking rules doesn't have well defined consequences, and the bounds for manipulation of that underlying structure without invoking UB are somewhat bound: You can add entries by calling `malloc`, vary entries using `realloc` and remove entries using `free`.

Comment: Breaking the rules in C may appear as though you've stepped across a boundary. In fact, that is the case for buffer overflows, for example. Sometimes you get an overflow that works... other times, you don't. Breaking rules doesn't have well defined consequences, and the bounds for manipulation of that underlying structure are somewhat bound: You can add entries by calling `malloc`, vary entries using `realloc` and remove entries using `free`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, after memory is consumed by the needs of programs, what is left is the heap.  In C that will be the memory available for the computer, for virtual machines it will be less than that.

But, this is the memory that can be used at run-time as your program needs memory dynamically.

You may want to look at this for more info:

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c28.htm

Comment: Who +1d this? I'm just curious as to what value to draw from this, because it seems like a completely invalid answer. Perhaps you can clarify... you're saying that 1/ once some memory is in use by a program, it's in the heap? Or are you saying 2/ once the program is finished with the memory, it goes into the heap? Either of these are *wrong*. Does this include register memory and memory on a rotational hard drive?

Comment: Also, that is an example of a really poor resource for learning C. If you need a manual to refer to, it's [the POSIX `malloc` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html), which you'll notice makes no reference to the term *heap*, as the people who wrote your *heap* understand (just as well as you should) that it isn't necessarily a *heap*; it's a *book-keeping space*.

Comment: @Sebivor - the memory that isn't used by the application is what I was calling the heap.  So you have all the allocations that is part of starting up an application, and the memory that is available for malloc is the heap.

Comment: According to the C language, the storage duration made available by `malloc` is called *allocated storage duration*; there's no mention at all of a *heap* in C. On x86 (due to assembly), you may be (typically) correct... but that's assembly, not C; there's no requirement that a *heap* be used; it could just as easily be a *stack* or some other kind of *graph*. In fact, I think an optimal implementation may head towards a *graph* of *heaps* allocated per *thread* which has edges corresponding to synchronisation.

Comment: [This reputable website](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Web_resources) lists your reference under the section entitled *"Stuff that should be avoided"*, for what it's worth. You should be citing from [the standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). Good luck finding a citation for *the heap*!

Answer (score 1):

Reading through this, this is actually beyond the realms of C. C doesn't specify that there's a *heap* behind `malloc`; it could just as easily be called a *linked list*; you're just calling it a *heap* by convention.

What the standard guarantees is that `malloc` will either return a pointer to an object that has *dynamic storage duration*, and your *heap* is just one type of data structure which facilitates the provision of such a storage duration. It's the common choice. Nonetheless, the very developers who wrote your *heap* have recognised that it might not be a *heap*, and so you'll see no reference of the term *heap* in [the POSIX `malloc` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) for example.

Other things that are beyond the realms of standard C include such details of the *machine code* binary which is no longer C source code following compilation. The layout details, though typical, are all implementation-specific as opposed to C-specific.

The *heap*, or whichever *book-keeping* data structure is used to account for allocations, is generated during runtime; as `malloc` is called, new entries are (presumably) added to it and as `free` is called, new entries are (again, presumably) removed from it.

As a result, there's generally no need to have a section in the machine code binary for objects allocated using `malloc`, however there are cases where applications are shipped standalone baked into microprocessors, and in some of these cases you might find that flash or otherwise non-volatile memory might be reserved for that use.

Comment: Heap space is sometimes allocated statically, thus included in the binary, in embedded systems. Basically pre-allocated storage space, and malloc/free would use that space instead of a process space allocated by the underlying runtime environment. Haven’t had to do that for some time, but used to.