# Heap in C++ create

Tags: c++, c, heap-memory

I would like to create a HEAP, something similar in C. My heap must realize such function MyMalloc, MyCalloc, MyRealloc.
Could you recommended literature which gives an opportunity to understand the HEAP, sample of HEAP?
I tried find in google, so I would like to hear your advices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some reading and other examples I have found for HEAP using google:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/heap.html
http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/heap.htm

I even found a link from this site:
[Heap Memory in C Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200628/heap-memory-in-c-programming)

Take in mind it took me two minutes to find all of these links. I've skimmed through them and it looks like all of them answer your questions, but if they don't then I suppose you do have good reason to ask this question. Still, google is your friend.