# Freeing string from a non constant pointer parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, constants

So i'm passing a string as parameter to my function and I dont know if I should free it or not. I'm creating this string at the function call, so I dont know if its a constant or not

```
    void myFunction(char *string)
    {
        //do stuff
        free (string); //im not sure about this line
    }


    int main()
    {
        myFunction("some text");
        return 0;
    }
```

The question is: should I free that string?

Comment: Generally you would want whatever code that created the string to be responsible for destroying it as well to avoid this sort of situation.

Comment: No, you don't have to. You're not even allowed to. String literals must _never_ be freed. Can't find a good duplicate… Only `free` what you have `malloc`ed (or `realloc`ed).

Comment: Also for future reference: Try to clearly state what your question is. This one looks more like some meditative insight ...

Comment: thanks for all the answers. And I'm sorry for the vague question

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to (and should not) free this string. You should only have to free things that you have used malloc, realloc, or calloc (as mentioned by sharth in the comments) on.

Comment: `calloc` would also qualify.

Comment: "You don't have to free this string" should read "You **must not** free this string".

Comment: Thanks @Kay. Edited for clarification. (Also, thanks for your contribution, @sharth)

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing a text constant (as you are in the example) - you **do not free it**.

It has *not* be malloc'ed, and trying to free it would probably cause a crash.

On a related note, in a situation where the string passed in may be an allocate block or may be a text constant, the callee cannot know which and therefore cannot call `free()`.  The *calling* function must do the right thing.

This is only natural.  The caller would have allocated the block, therefore it should be responsible for freeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `free` in such context is actually undefined behaviour, see C99 `7.20.3.2` *The free function*, p.2 (emphasis mine):

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument **does not
>   match a pointer** earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc`
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or
>   `realloc`, the **behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done like below then you might consider freeing it, but as said in comments code that created the string should be responsible for destroying it. As in below code memory has been allocated in heap you are supposed to free it.

```
void myFunction(char *string)
{
    //do stuff
    // free (string); do not free here
}


int main()
{
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    myFunction(str);

    // after you are done with str (string)
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

But in your case you have passed string literal, no need to free it, as it does not reside in  [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200628/heap-memory-in-c-programming).

Answer (score -1):

**you have not allocated memory for it, so you don't need to free it**.
I think you want this:

```
#include"stdio.h"
 void myFunction(char **string)
    {
        //do stuff
    printf("%s",*string);
    free (*string); 
    }


    int main()
    {
     char *p =(char *)(malloc(20));
     strcpy(p,"sometest");
     myFunction(&p);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Freeing a block that you did not allocate is a bad idea.  It would probably be best to move the malloc into `myFUnction`

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work.  I said it was a bad idea.  Making it a reference didn't change that.

Comment: Memory you allocate can be freed from anywhere, till have the address , so I just changed it to pass by reference. This idea is usually used  when you need to fill the values somewhere else in the buffer and use it somewhere else.

Comment: "Anywhere" is a bit too broad. In sufficiently large/complex projects (especially when using external libraries), you must take care to be sure that you free memory with the `free` function that corresponds to the function that allocated it originally (i.e. from the same libc). This is a strong argument for the caller-allocates-and-deallocates pattern (and against caller-allocates-callee-frees).

Comment: Memory you allocate using malloc comes from the heap area so it's scope is not just the function or block, that's what I did. I used pass by addr and freed the mem in another func. And it is upto you where you free the memory . But if my answer is down voted that's fine as I think it's a game going on here not a portal at this instance.